# How do I remove a specific "sequence" from a Javascript string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as following:

```
Well, here we are.^2000 Ain't much to look at, is it?^2000 Came here on a Wednesday night once.^1000 It was actually pretty crowded.^1000 But on a Tuesday evening .^300 .^300 .^1000 I guess it's just you^1000 and me.^3000 Heh.
```

Now I was wondering how would I remove all the `^` and the numbers that followed after the `^` so it would eventually output the following,

```
Well, here we are. Ain't much to look at, is it? Came here on a Wednesday night once. It was actually pretty crowded. But on a Tuesday evening . . . I guess it's just you and me. Heh.
```

Comment: you want to use [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
var res = str.replace( new RegExp("(\\^\\d+)","gm"), "");
```

Where `str` is the string, the regex matches `^<number>` and replacing string is `""`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you want to use something called [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var html = $('#start').html();

  var output = html.replace(/(\^\d{2,4})/g, '');

  $('#results').html(output);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
  Well, here we are.^2000 Ain't much to look at, is it?^2000 Came here on a Wednesday night once.^1000 It was actually pretty crowded.^1000 But on a Tuesday evening .^300 .^300 .^1000 I guess it's just you^1000 and me.^3000 Heh.
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
```